# implement neo4j customize elevator

Tags: java, neo4j

now i tried to implement a project using neo4j.
i implemented my evaluator. each node on the bfs has two sets: in and out.
meet one node on the way, do some intersection check and decide to go on or not.
but my code right now is not coming into the evaluator. i added some print check point. nothing shows up.

```
public final class MyEvaluator implements Evaluator {

        ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>> templin;
        ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>> templout;
        Node tempnode;
        public MyEvaluator(Node node, ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>> lin,ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>> lout ) { 
            templin=lin;
            templout=lout;
            tempnode=node;
        }
        @Override
        public Evaluation evaluate(Path path) { 
        Node pc=path.endNode();
        System.out.println("test!!!");
         if (Collections.disjoint(templin.get((int) pc.getProperty("nodeID")), templout.get((int) tempnode.getProperty("nodeID")))){
             //Returns true if the two specified collections have no elements in common.
              //System.out.println("here");
            templin.get((int) pc.getProperty("nodeID")).add((int) tempnode.getProperty("nodeID"));
            System.out.println(templin.get((int) pc.getProperty("nodeID")));
             return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
          }else{
             return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_PRUNE;
          }                                                                                                                        
     }
    }
    public Traverser nodes( Node node, ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>> lin,ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>> lout )
    {   

        return  friendsTraversal
                .evaluator(new MyEvaluator(node, lin, lout))
                .traverse( node );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have to iterate over the traverser results, traversal is a lazy operation.

```
for (Node n: nodes(...)) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: thanks. what do you mean by lazy operation? do i need use iterator?